# mpi, cannot allocate slots even though processors are available

Tags: mpi

i am running an mpi program on the below linux machine resources:

```
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                32
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-31
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    8
```

the problem happens when i spawn the processes using:

```
    MPI_Comm_spawn("./processes/montecarlo", array_of_argv, numworkers,
            MPI_INFO_NULL,
            0, MPI_COMM_SELF, &workercomm, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);
```

numworkers if i set it to 30( as i have 32 CPU) or even to 20, or to 15 ==> i w ill have the message of:

```
   There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 21 slots
   that were requested by the application:
   ./processes/montecarlo

    Either request fewer slots for your application, or make more slots 
    available for use.
```

Comment: there are 32 threads, but MPI likely only considers 16 cores. what is your MPI library & version ? what is your command line ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet i just tried 14 workers and it worked, so you must b right about 16 cores. the fact that CPU: 32. i thought i have 32 cpu. mpic++ --version ==> g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet when i run this from java: Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() i got that i have 32 CPU.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet no cmd line, this is integrated in c++ code. i am nw tryign to do: --oversubscribe --hostfile hostfile. but am not sure about the results

Comment: assuming you are using Open MPI, you can `mpirun --use-hwthread-cpus` in order to have 1 hyperthread = 1slot (e.g. 32 slots on your system)

Comment: how to pass --use-hwthread-cpus to MPI_Comm_spawn?

Comment: are you saying it is not working when you pass it to `mpirun` ? which MPI library (vendor and version) are you using ?

Comment: i am not using mpirun to launch jobs. i am using MPI_Comm_spawn as you can see from my question.

Comment: your question does not state how you are starting your MPI application. anyway, you can set an environment variable before starting your app. `export OMPI_MCA_hwloc_base_use_hwthreads_as_cpus=true`

Comment: ok sorry . can i do this from c++ code?. i need to do something from code.

Comment: **before** `MPI_Init()`, `setenv("OMPI_MCA_hwloc_base_use_hwthreads_as_cpus", "true", true)`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet can you please put your comment in the answer box